# Expresso Store PHP Error when login into the CP

Tags: expresso-store

I'm using Expresso Store 2 with the latest download of 2.2.0 and using EE version of 2.7.2.

When log into the CP and then try and view the site I get a PHP Error page with the following lines:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: include(/Users/grahamcopekoga/Documents/sites/vintageceramics/fukuoka/expressionengine/modules/member/mod.member_register.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory
Filename: composer/ClassLoader.php
Line Number: 269
```

AND THIS:

```
A PHP Error was encountered
Severity: Warning
Message: include(): Failed opening '/Users/grahamcopekoga/Documents/sites/vintageceramics/fukuoka/expressionengine/modules/member/mod.member_register.php' for inclusion (include_path='.:/Applications/MAMP/bin/php/php5.4.10/lib/php')
Filename: composer/ClassLoader.php
Line Number: 269
```

AND THIS:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Member_register' not found in /Users/grahamcopekoga/Documents/sites/vintageceramics/fukuoka/expressionengine/third_party/store/src/Store/Service/MemberService.php on line 23
```

I'm on a test server running MAMP. When I log out of the CP I can view the site, so its a login in issue with Store.

Does anyone know why?

Many thanks in advance.

Comment: Hmmm...that's certainly not a common error and the first thing that comes to mind is that there might have been a problem with installation. Would you be able to try re-copying over all of Store's files to their relevant locations in EE and try again? Do you still get the same thing?

Comment: @Ian I did try that, but will try it again and let you know. It could be an issue with the EE set up on the test server.

Comment: Are you running EE Core?

Comment: @AdrianMacneil Yes, I'm running EE CORE

Comment: Graham, that will be why. Store provides options to integrate with member management at the point of checkout but if you're only running the Core then the Member module wont be included. You can see a [table of features between Core and full version here](https://store.ellislab.com/).

Comment: @Ian Many thanks. I am developing in EE and will upgrade at a later date, which should solve the issues.

Answer (score 1):

Per the comments - OP was running ExpressionEngine Core edition.

Expresso Store requires the full version of ExpressionEngine, as it relies on internal member management features only available in the full version.

Comment: Thank you for the information, very useful for everyone to know.

Comment: It should probably also be noted that using EE Core for commercial purposes, as presumably a site using Store would be, is in violation of the Core license agreement.